# Check if property exists in RavenDB

Tags: ravendb

I want to add property to existing document (using clues form http://ravendb.net/docs/client-api/partial-document-updates). But before adding want to check if that property already exists in my database.

Is any "special,proper ravendB way" to achieve that?
Or just load document and check if this property is null or not?

Comment: See the discussion here:
https://groups.google.com/group/ravendb/browse_thread/thread/cf5617b76d40d915/6b07812282999237?lnk=gst&q=property+exists#6b07812282999237

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using a set based database update. You carry it out using JavaScript, which fortunately is similar enough to C# to make it a pretty painless process for anybody.  Here's an example of an update I just ran.

**Note**: You have to be **very careful** doing this because errors in your script may have undesired results.  For example, in my code CustomId contains something like '1234-1'. In my first iteration of writing the script, I had:

```
product.Order = parseInt(product.CustomId.split('-'));
```

Notice I forgot the indexer after split. The result?  An error, right?  Nope.  Order had the value of 12341!  It is supposed to be 1. So be careful and be sure to test it thoroughly.

Example:

Job has a Products property (a collection) and I'm adding the new Order property to existing Products.

```
ravenSession.Advanced.DocumentStore.DatabaseCommands.UpdateByIndex(
    "Raven/DocumentsByEntityName",
    new IndexQuery { Query = "Tag:Jobs" },
    new ScriptedPatchRequest { Script =
        @"
        this.Products.Map(function(product) {   
            if(product.Order == undefined)
            {
                product.Order = parseInt(product.CustomId.split('-')[1]);
            }
            return product;
        });"
    }
);
```

I referenced these pages to build it:

[set based ops](http://ravendb.net/docs/client-api/set-based-operations)

[partial document updates](http://ravendb.net/docs/client-api/partial-document-updates) (in particular the [Map](http://ravendb.net/docs/client-api/partial-document-updates#map) section)